# MagicalRecord Auto Saving entities while created even without calling Save

Tags: entity-framework, core-data, magicalrecord-2.2

I have created entity with following methods

```
NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
Contact *contact = [Contact MR_createInContext:localContext];

And

Contact *contact = [Contact MR_createEntity];
```

Above methods are called inside a for loop and values are set. After that, I didn't executed any save method for above entity instance. However, after loop is completed, when I read from coredata,

```
NSArray *savedContacts = [Contact MR_findAll];
NSLog(@"Saved contacts : %d", [savedContacts count]);
```

It prints the saved entities count. So, are these entities autosaved? or are there any settings that is causing MagicalRecord to save each entities?

Any sort of information would be very essential. I am using MagicalRecord version 2.2. The issue has been opened [here](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/issues/480) which points to ask question on SO with MagicalRecord tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause of this behavior.

FROM README DOCUMENT OF MAGICAL RECORD : CHANGES TO SAVING

> `MR_save` has been temporarily restored to it's original state of
>   running synchronously on the current thread, and saving to the
>   persistent store. However, the **`MR_save` method is marked as
>   deprecated and will be removed in the next major release of
>   MagicalRecord (version 3.0)**. You should use
>   `MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait` if you want the same behaviour in
>   future versions of the library.

So if you create a context from **MR_contextForCurrentThread**, then above rule will apply which causes each object you create to be saved in persistent store even if you don't call the save method. Similarly, the **MR_createEntity** method uses context from **MR_contextForCurrentThread** which was causing an object to save it. As stated above the MR_save is deprecated and will be removed in MR version 3.0 which will prevent it from autosaving in future even you create context via **MR_contextForCurrentThread**.

To create object with auto save off you can use local context from **MR_context** only as below :

```
NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_context];
Contact *contact = [Contact MR_createInContext:localContext];
```